# Loading spec.opts when testing pure Ruby program

Tags: ruby, command-line, rspec

I'm writing spec for my pure ruby program and what I want to do is to somehow load `spec.opts` in my test suite.

I Rails we can just create a corresponding file and put it in the `spec` folder of an app. But when I put a `spec.opts` file in folder with my program in it - the magic doesn't work :)

My motivation is to get rid of passing options, i.e.

```
spec my_program_spec.rb -c -f s
```

every time I run `spec` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The --options flag lets you specify a file of options rather than entering them one-by-one:

```
spec --options spec/spec.opts
```

You could also create a Rakefile in the root directory of the project and put something like this in it:

```
require 'spec/rake/spectask'

Spec::Rake::SpecTask.new do |t|
  t.spec_opts = ['--options', 'spec/spec.opts']
end
```

This would let you run your test suite with the file of options using Rake:

```
rake spec
```

(I haven't used RSpec 2 yet, so all of this is RSpec 1).

Answer (score 5):

Is this Rspec 2? If so, options go into `.rspec` instead of `spec.opts`. `.rspec` can go in the project root, or in the user home directory (./.rspec or ~/.rspec).

If it is Rspec 1, put `spec.opts` in the project root folder.